# Reordering values within row R dataframe using regex

Tags: r

I have a paired data value dataframe like this

```
> df <- data.frame(int1 = c("A", "B", "Ci"), int2 = c("Ca", "Cg", "A"), value = c(3,6,2))
> df
  int1 int2 value
1    A   Ca     3
2    B   Cg     6
3   Ci    A     2
```

I would like to reorder the values in the first two columns rowwise, searching for a regex or using `%in%`, such that all the all the values matching "C" are in the same column, and the all the other ones are in another column.

I'm trying to get to this:

```
  C_int other_int value
1    Ca         A     3
2    Cg         B     6
3    Ci         A     2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option in `base R`- loop over the rows with `apply`, MARGIN = 1, and `order` the values based on the occurrence of 'C' in the elements, and assign back the ordered elements

```
df[1:2] <- t(apply(df[1:2], 1, function(x) x[order(!grepl("C", x))]))
```

-output

```
> df
  int1 int2 value
1   Ca    A     3
2   Cg    B     6
3   Ci    A     2
> str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ int1 : chr  "Ca" "Cg" "Ci"
 $ int2 : chr  "A" "B" "A"
 $ value: int  3 6 2
```

Comment: to alternatively use `%in%`, this works (just to make this more generalisable): `df[1:2] <-
    t(apply(df[1:2], 1, function(x) x[order(!(x %in% c("Ca", "Cg", "Ci")))]))`. Apologies, couldn't edit answer.

Comment: @steve_b But would that be more narrower than generalized.  `grepl` will find whereever there is 'C' substring

Comment: Absolutely! re: generalisable, I just meant this question thread on stackoverflow, not the solution itself. I meant to supplement the answer so that if someone (like me) sometimes has a list of specific matches, or sometimes has a substring, they now have examples of approaches suitable for each. I don't think it warrants a separate SO question and answer though as they're such similar tasks.

Comment: @steve_b Your code also works fine for this example.  When I read your descriiption in the post, it says `such that all the all the values matching "C" are in the same column`.  Suppose you have element like 'Cf', 'Ce', etc in a different data, then you have to adjust the code in `%in%`, whereas `grepl` doesn't.  But, having said that, each have its own limitations

Comment: I always assumed that absolute matching via `%in%` would be faster than `grepl` over large datasets (part of my reason for including the alternative), but I don't actually know. Do you know if something like `x %in% c("a","b","c")` is intrinsically faster than `grepl(paste0(c("a","b","c"), collapse="|"), x)`? This is not a challenge, I'm genuinely curious if there is indeed a fundamental difference in the way they work. Thanks.

Comment: @steve_b that could be the way if efficiency is a criteria.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach using `split()`:

```r
df[1:2] <- df[1:2] %>%
  t() %>%
  split(!str_detect(., "C"))
df
#>   int1 int2 value
#> 1   Ca    A     3
#> 2   Cg    B     6
#> 3   Ci    A     2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Elegant. Sadly, through no fault of the answerer, this doesn't immediately hold up when there is no match for "C". This was my fault in incompletely defining the question, however.